# Gnuplot, improving staircase function plot

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following script:

```
set xlabel "y" 
set ylabel "rw[j]"
set title "P-D diagram"
set xzeroaxis
unset key

plot [0.5:1] \
-5.71429*x title "L[-5]" linetype 1, \
-4.28571*x title "U[-5]" linetype 3, \
-4.71429*x title "L[-4]" linetype 1, \
-3.28571*x title "U[-4]" linetype 3, \
-3.71429*x title "L[-3]" linetype 1, \
-2.28571*x title "U[-3]" linetype 3, \
-2.71429*x title "L[-2]" linetype 1, \
-1.28571*x title "U[-2]" linetype 3, \
-1.71429*x title "L[-1]" linetype 1, \
-0.285714*x title "U[-1]" linetype 3, \
-0.714286*x title "L[0]" linetype 1, \
0.714286*x title "U[0]" linetype 3, \
0.285714*x title "L[1]" linetype 1, \
1.71429*x title "U[1]" linetype 3, \
1.28571*x title "L[2]" linetype 1, \
2.71429*x title "U[2]" linetype 3, \
2.28571*x title "L[3]" linetype 1, \
3.71429*x title "U[3]" linetype 3, \
3.28571*x title "L[4]" linetype 1, \
4.71429*x title "U[4]" linetype 3, \
4.28571*x title "L[5]" linetype 1, \
5.71429*x title "U[5]" linetype 3, \
(0.500000<= x && x <= 0.531250) ? 0.000000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.531250<= x && x <= 0.562500) ? 0.000000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.562500<= x && x <= 0.593750) ? 0.000000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.593750<= x && x <= 0.625000) ? 0.000000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.625000<= x && x <= 0.656250) ? 0.000000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.656250<= x && x <= 0.687500) ? 0.000000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.687500<= x && x <= 0.718750) ? 0.000000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.718750<= x && x <= 0.750000) ? 0.000000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.750000<= x && x <= 0.781250) ? 0.000000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.781250<= x && x <= 0.812500) ? 0.000000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.812500<= x && x <= 0.843750) ? 0.000000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.843750<= x && x <= 0.875000) ? 0.000000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.875000<= x && x <= 0.906250) ? 0.000000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.906250<= x && x <= 0.937500) ? 0.000000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.937500<= x && x <= 0.968750) ? 0.000000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.968750<= x && x <= 1.000000) ? 0.000000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.500000<= x && x <= 0.531250) ? -2.312500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.531250<= x && x <= 0.562500) ? -2.500000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.562500<= x && x <= 0.593750) ? -2.625000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.593750<= x && x <= 0.625000) ? -2.750000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.625000<= x && x <= 0.656250) ? -2.937500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.656250<= x && x <= 0.687500) ? -3.062500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.687500<= x && x <= 0.718750) ? -3.187500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.718750<= x && x <= 0.750000) ? -3.375000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.750000<= x && x <= 0.781250) ? -3.500000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.781250<= x && x <= 0.812500) ? -3.625000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.812500<= x && x <= 0.843750) ? -3.812500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.843750<= x && x <= 0.875000) ? -3.937500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.875000<= x && x <= 0.906250) ? -4.125000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.906250<= x && x <= 0.937500) ? -4.250000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.937500<= x && x <= 0.968750) ? -4.375000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.968750<= x && x <= 1.000000) ? -4.562500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.500000<= x && x <= 0.531250) ? -1.812500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.531250<= x && x <= 0.562500) ? -1.937500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.562500<= x && x <= 0.593750) ? -2.062500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.593750<= x && x <= 0.625000) ? -2.187500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.625000<= x && x <= 0.656250) ? -2.312500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.656250<= x && x <= 0.687500) ? -2.437500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.687500<= x && x <= 0.718750) ? -2.500000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.718750<= x && x <= 0.750000) ? -2.625000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.750000<= x && x <= 0.781250) ? -2.750000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.781250<= x && x <= 0.812500) ? -2.875000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.812500<= x && x <= 0.843750) ? -3.000000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.843750<= x && x <= 0.875000) ? -3.125000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.875000<= x && x <= 0.906250) ? -3.250000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.906250<= x && x <= 0.937500) ? -3.312500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.937500<= x && x <= 0.968750) ? -3.437500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.968750<= x && x <= 1.000000) ? -3.562500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.500000<= x && x <= 0.531250) ? -1.312500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.531250<= x && x <= 0.562500) ? -1.437500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.562500<= x && x <= 0.593750) ? -1.500000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.593750<= x && x <= 0.625000) ? -1.562500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.625000<= x && x <= 0.656250) ? -1.687500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.656250<= x && x <= 0.687500) ? -1.750000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.687500<= x && x <= 0.718750) ? -1.812500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.718750<= x && x <= 0.750000) ? -1.937500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.750000<= x && x <= 0.781250) ? -2.000000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.781250<= x && x <= 0.812500) ? -2.062500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.812500<= x && x <= 0.843750) ? -2.187500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.843750<= x && x <= 0.875000) ? -2.250000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.875000<= x && x <= 0.906250) ? -2.375000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.906250<= x && x <= 0.937500) ? -2.437500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.937500<= x && x <= 0.968750) ? -2.500000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.968750<= x && x <= 1.000000) ? -2.625000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.500000<= x && x <= 0.531250) ? -0.812500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.531250<= x && x <= 0.562500) ? -0.875000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.562500<= x && x <= 0.593750) ? -0.937500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.593750<= x && x <= 0.625000) ? -1.000000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.625000<= x && x <= 0.656250) ? -1.062500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.656250<= x && x <= 0.687500) ? -1.125000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.687500<= x && x <= 0.718750) ? -1.125000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.718750<= x && x <= 0.750000) ? -1.187500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.750000<= x && x <= 0.781250) ? -1.250000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.781250<= x && x <= 0.812500) ? -1.312500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.812500<= x && x <= 0.843750) ? -1.375000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.843750<= x && x <= 0.875000) ? -1.437500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.875000<= x && x <= 0.906250) ? -1.500000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.906250<= x && x <= 0.937500) ? -1.500000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.937500<= x && x <= 0.968750) ? -1.562500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.968750<= x && x <= 1.000000) ? -1.625000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.500000<= x && x <= 0.531250) ? -0.312500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.531250<= x && x <= 0.562500) ? -0.375000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.562500<= x && x <= 0.593750) ? -0.375000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.593750<= x && x <= 0.625000) ? -0.375000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.625000<= x && x <= 0.656250) ? -0.437500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.656250<= x && x <= 0.687500) ? -0.437500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.687500<= x && x <= 0.718750) ? -0.437500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.718750<= x && x <= 0.750000) ? -0.500000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.750000<= x && x <= 0.781250) ? -0.500000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.781250<= x && x <= 0.812500) ? -0.500000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.812500<= x && x <= 0.843750) ? -0.562500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.843750<= x && x <= 0.875000) ? -0.562500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.875000<= x && x <= 0.906250) ? -0.625000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.906250<= x && x <= 0.937500) ? -0.625000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.937500<= x && x <= 0.968750) ? -0.625000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.968750<= x && x <= 1.000000) ? -0.687500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.500000<= x && x <= 0.531250) ? 0.312500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.531250<= x && x <= 0.562500) ? 0.375000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.562500<= x && x <= 0.593750) ? 0.375000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.593750<= x && x <= 0.625000) ? 0.375000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.625000<= x && x <= 0.656250) ? 0.437500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.656250<= x && x <= 0.687500) ? 0.437500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.687500<= x && x <= 0.718750) ? 0.437500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.718750<= x && x <= 0.750000) ? 0.500000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.750000<= x && x <= 0.781250) ? 0.500000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.781250<= x && x <= 0.812500) ? 0.500000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.812500<= x && x <= 0.843750) ? 0.562500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.843750<= x && x <= 0.875000) ? 0.562500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.875000<= x && x <= 0.906250) ? 0.625000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.906250<= x && x <= 0.937500) ? 0.625000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.937500<= x && x <= 0.968750) ? 0.625000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.968750<= x && x <= 1.000000) ? 0.687500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.500000<= x && x <= 0.531250) ? 0.812500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.531250<= x && x <= 0.562500) ? 0.875000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.562500<= x && x <= 0.593750) ? 0.937500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.593750<= x && x <= 0.625000) ? 1.000000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.625000<= x && x <= 0.656250) ? 1.062500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.656250<= x && x <= 0.687500) ? 1.125000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.687500<= x && x <= 0.718750) ? 1.125000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.718750<= x && x <= 0.750000) ? 1.187500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.750000<= x && x <= 0.781250) ? 1.250000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.781250<= x && x <= 0.812500) ? 1.312500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.812500<= x && x <= 0.843750) ? 1.375000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.843750<= x && x <= 0.875000) ? 1.437500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.875000<= x && x <= 0.906250) ? 1.500000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.906250<= x && x <= 0.937500) ? 1.500000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.937500<= x && x <= 0.968750) ? 1.562500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.968750<= x && x <= 1.000000) ? 1.625000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.500000<= x && x <= 0.531250) ? 1.312500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.531250<= x && x <= 0.562500) ? 1.437500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.562500<= x && x <= 0.593750) ? 1.500000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.593750<= x && x <= 0.625000) ? 1.562500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.625000<= x && x <= 0.656250) ? 1.687500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.656250<= x && x <= 0.687500) ? 1.750000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.687500<= x && x <= 0.718750) ? 1.812500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.718750<= x && x <= 0.750000) ? 1.937500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.750000<= x && x <= 0.781250) ? 2.000000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.781250<= x && x <= 0.812500) ? 2.062500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.812500<= x && x <= 0.843750) ? 2.187500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.843750<= x && x <= 0.875000) ? 2.250000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.875000<= x && x <= 0.906250) ? 2.375000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.906250<= x && x <= 0.937500) ? 2.437500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.937500<= x && x <= 0.968750) ? 2.500000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.968750<= x && x <= 1.000000) ? 2.625000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.500000<= x && x <= 0.531250) ? 1.812500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.531250<= x && x <= 0.562500) ? 1.937500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.562500<= x && x <= 0.593750) ? 2.062500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.593750<= x && x <= 0.625000) ? 2.187500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.625000<= x && x <= 0.656250) ? 2.312500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.656250<= x && x <= 0.687500) ? 2.437500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.687500<= x && x <= 0.718750) ? 2.500000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.718750<= x && x <= 0.750000) ? 2.625000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.750000<= x && x <= 0.781250) ? 2.750000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.781250<= x && x <= 0.812500) ? 2.875000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.812500<= x && x <= 0.843750) ? 3.000000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.843750<= x && x <= 0.875000) ? 3.125000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.875000<= x && x <= 0.906250) ? 3.250000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.906250<= x && x <= 0.937500) ? 3.312500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.937500<= x && x <= 0.968750) ? 3.437500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.968750<= x && x <= 1.000000) ? 3.562500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.500000<= x && x <= 0.531250) ? 2.312500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.531250<= x && x <= 0.562500) ? 2.500000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.562500<= x && x <= 0.593750) ? 2.625000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.593750<= x && x <= 0.625000) ? 2.750000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.625000<= x && x <= 0.656250) ? 2.937500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.656250<= x && x <= 0.687500) ? 3.062500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.687500<= x && x <= 0.718750) ? 3.187500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.718750<= x && x <= 0.750000) ? 3.375000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.750000<= x && x <= 0.781250) ? 3.500000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.781250<= x && x <= 0.812500) ? 3.625000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.812500<= x && x <= 0.843750) ? 3.812500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.843750<= x && x <= 0.875000) ? 3.937500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.875000<= x && x <= 0.906250) ? 4.125000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.906250<= x && x <= 0.937500) ? 4.250000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.937500<= x && x <= 0.968750) ? 4.375000:1.0/0.0 linetype 4,\
(0.968750<= x && x <= 1.000000) ? 4.562500:1.0/0.0 linetype 4
pause - 1
```

that plots the following:
[image]

I wish I were able to plot an actual staircase instead of those jumps, also it does look to me that given two consecutives orange lines in the y axis, there's a gap `delta_y`, but it shouldn't be like that given that the `y` axis is partitioned into contiguous intervals.

Any hints?
(PS. the script is generated by a program, my gnuplot version is 5.2)

Comment: Save your staircase data to a file and use the `steps`, `histeps` plotting style.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.0/steps.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `int` function to round down (positive) numbers to the next integer. Using the right factors, this yields proper steps. For example, you can do the following to plot `5*x` in steps of size `0.31250`:

```
rounddown(x,p) = int(x/p)*p
plot rounddown(5*x,0.31250)
```

Note that for low resolutions, it may be necessary to increase the number of samples, e.g. as follows:

```
set samples 10000
```